# How many BA tier points can one be short vs official guideline and still retain status?

Tags: british-airways

I know it's somewhere between 5 and 25 but not sure how much?

Also does one need to call executive club to retain the status (when short a handful of points) or is it automatic?

For instance, obtaining (or maintaining) Bronze status officially requires 300 tier points to be flown in that year. Is 290 sufficient? What's the magic number?

Is the tolerance different for obtaining a status for the first time, vs maintaining existing status?

Comment: What makes you think there are unofficial guidelines on top of the official guidelines that are enforced consistently? Retaining status when short a few points seems like a gesture of goodwill from BA rather than strict policy.

Comment: I don't think BA is making special exemptions for almost-Bronzes.

Comment: JJJ: because it happened to me in the past. I was short a few points to retain Silver and BA told me there was some tolerance and let me keep my status. I just don't remember how much the tolerance was.